# Roll-your-own tracking or Google Analytics + API for internal dashboard?

Tags: architecture, google-analytics, usage-statistics

I want to track usage on my website, where users can post ads. I want to show the users how many people have looked at their ads, etc., on an internal dashboard.

It seems like I have two ways to go:

1. Roll my own complete solution. Set up a way to track and store the statistics in my database.
2. Use a pre-existing solution, like Google Analytics, to track the usage and then use an API to access the data and perhaps save it my DB.

I'm leaning towards the second solution, but it's not totally straight forward. Since I can tag usage with custom variables in Google Analytics, I can associate an event with i.e the ad ID. The problem is that I want to access the data in more high level way, like "Show me how many visits all coffee table ads for this user has gotten".

It doesn't seem so viable to query the tracking service with all the corresponding ID:s to that question (the list of all IDs for objects which are coffee tables and owned by a particular user can be quite long).

This means that I'll have to periodically query the API for statistics about all IDs and then store it, so I can query it with the aforementioned question.

The upside of using an existing service is that the service has implemented tracking in a much better way than if I do it myself (how to separate unique visitors, get information about geolocation, demographics, etc.) and that the service will track everything. So if I down the line want to access another datapoint, it's already tracked historically.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: "Homegrown vs. Google Analytics" sounds like a wrong dichotomy. There is tons of analytics software out there and there might be packages that suit your needs better than GA. Building your own is (my opinion only) worth your time only in very  special use cases, if you need full analytics coverage you should extend an existing solution (maybe one of the free packages like OWA, Piwik or SnowPlow).

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I'm looking around to find different packages. I have looked at Piwik abit, but will check out the other two you recommend, thanks.